# Double Tap Key Bindings Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, key-bindings

```
public void fullscreenKey(final JFrame frame)
{
    k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0);
    getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(k, k.toString());
    getActionMap().put(k.toString(), new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            fullscreen(!f1, frame);
            f1 = !f1;
        }
    });  
}
```

Whenever I call this method into other classes, nothing happens. I can't make this method static because of getInputMap and getActionMap. I call with Main main = new Main(); main.fullscreenKey(frame); This method is called in the Main constructor. How can I call this method in other classes and have it work?

Comment: Just make getInputMap and getActionMap static as well?

Comment: @JeffLaJoie `getInputMap` and `getActionMap` are methods of `JComponent`, they form part of the [Swing key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), he can't make them static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after or not

```
public void fullscreenKey(JComponent comp, final JFrame frame)
{
    k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0);
    comp.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(k, k.toString());
    comp.getActionMap().put(k.toString(), new AbstractAction()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            fullscreen(!f1, frame);
            f1 = !f1;
        }
    });  
}
```

If you're looking for a "global" key handler instead (ie you want to handle the key stroke at anytime in your application), you could look at [Toolkit.addAWTEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29), this is very low level so it might take a little effort to it to work properly.

You could also look at the [KeyboardFocusManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html) ([Java Global JFrame KeyListener](http://jonathanweatherhead.com/2011/09/16/java-global-jframe-key-listener/))

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I couldn't use this. in static methods, but putting it as an arg was something I never thought of. As for the links, I will look into those. I think a shared method would work the same though.